# UIToolBar does not use the whole width of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

My UIToolBar does not want to use the whole width of the screen.

I do not use any TextField, but adding the toolbar as a sub-view of a UIPickerView.

```
let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))

@IBAction func addDistanceToCollection(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        createPickerView()
        createToolBar()
    }

func createPickerView() {
    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pickerView)

    pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.addSubview(toolBar)
}

func createToolBar() {
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: nil)
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
}
```

I also tried u use `pickerView.frame.width` as a toolbar width, but it does not seem to fix the problem. Looks like the width is some const value that i just can not change.

[image]

Comment: can you set it as inputview ? as `picker.inputView = toolbar`

Comment: or set contraint to toolbar as well ?

Comment: no, i can not set it as an inputView

Comment: which constraint do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set constraint to toolbar as well

```
func createPickerView() {
    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pickerView)
    view.addSubview(toolBar)
    
    pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pickerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code, but the app crashed with the following stacktrace:                                  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x280c85100 "UIPickerView:0x137f098d0.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x280c85680 "UILayoutGuide:0x2820c80e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException `

Comment: have you added the same code ? add constraint after adding toolbar to pickerView ...

Comment: hm, the app does not crash anymore, but the UIToolBar is unfortunately not visible :(

Comment: can you set it as `pickerView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar` ?

Comment: unfortunately not, the error says `Cannot find 'toolbar' in scope`

Comment: give it a try ... add toolbar in view .. instead of picker .... updated my code .. copy paste it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218120/discussion-between-jawadali-and-artiom-lemiasheuski).